# Shuffle three cards

Tags: java, shuffle

Question: How do I go about setting the ActionListener of my Shuffle button to do just what the button declares it does, and that is, to shuffle the 3 cards (out of 54 in an image folder) displayed on the screen? They appear randomly each time I run the program, and that's fine and all, but I'm needing to add a shuffle button that'll allow those changes to happen without having to restart the program. 
Here is what I've got so far..

```
//Jeffrey Zachary
//Advanced Java: Sept 15 2013
//Display 3 cards, shuffle them when called to do so

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class DisplayCards extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private JPanel cards;
private JButton shuffle;
private JLabel c1, c2, c3;
private Container contents;
private ImageIcon[] imIc;

 int cardA = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 54);
 int cardB = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 54);
 int cardC = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 54);

//create variables to store the random number for card 
private ImageIcon firstCard = new ImageIcon("card/" + cardA + ".png");
private ImageIcon secondCard = new ImageIcon("card/" + cardB + ".png");
private ImageIcon thirdCard = new ImageIcon("card/" + cardC + ".png");

public DisplayCards(){
    super("Display three cards");
    contents = getContentPane();
    contents.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Creating card labels
c1 = new JLabel(firstCard, JLabel.CENTER);
c2 = new JLabel(secondCard, JLabel.CENTER);
c3 = new JLabel(thirdCard, JLabel.CENTER);

    //Creating panel
cards = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    //Creating button
shuffle = new JButton("Shuffle");
shuffle.addActionListener(this);
    //Adding buttons
cards.add(shuffle, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    //Adding labels
cards.add(c1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
cards.add(c2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
cards.add(c3, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
contents.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
setResizable(false);
setSize(255, 177);
setVisible(true);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DisplayCards dc = new DisplayCards();

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == shuffle){

    }

}

}
```

Can't create a new homework tag (hint hint) :)   -No holding hands here-

Comment: What have you tried, we will be glad to help you if you have a problem, but we won't solve your homework instead

Comment: I suggest you separate the display/GUI code for the card/deck handling code.  Trying to mix your logic in one class is likely to lead to confusion and make it hard to unit test.  I suggest you write a unit test for how your crads/deck should behave i.e. without gui code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == shuffle) {
    cardA = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 54);
    while(cardB == cardA){
        cardB = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 54);
        }
    while (cardC == cardB || cardC == cardB){
        cardC = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 54);
    }

    firstCard = new ImageIcon("card/" + Integer.toString(cardA) + ".png");
    secondCard = new ImageIcon("card/" + Integer.toString(cardB) + ".png");
    thirdCard = new ImageIcon("card/" + Integer.toString(cardC) + ".png");
    DisplayCards()
}
```

}

Something like this with loops preventing the cards from matching may be appropriate here, as it is a small number of cards you need to confirm the uniqueness of.

The loops keep creating a random number until it does not match the previous numbers.  Once done you re-select the appropriate cards and re-display them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it should work. The idea is to link an `ActionEvent` to the code you want to execute each time the button is hit. Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for details.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == shuffle) {
        // add code here for shuffling 3 cards
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was just pointing him the solution for his question, not solving his homework. But you are right, I will edit my answer since it is not entirely correct.